# Sorting out the dublettes in SQL table

Tags: sql, mysql

I give an anology of my real problem below:

Imagine a website showing articles and all articles have comments associated with it. Now I want to get the articles that have comments that are commented bigger than a certain date, let say 2011-02-02. I also want to get the comment nearest in time to 2011-02-02. Don't forget that every article have more than one comment associated with it. I want this to happen in one single SQL query.

I found it hard to explain my problem so I give the SQL code:

```
SELECT articles.*, comments.date AS date
FROM articles, comments
WHERE comments.commentId in (SELECT commentId
                             FROM   comments
                             WHERE  date > 2011-02-02
                             ORDER BY date asc
                             LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY comments.date desc
```

The problem lies in the member section of the SQL query. Because it is only returning one single row. i want this to happen for each article

Comment: Do you mean "articles that have comments that are commented with a date greater than a certain date"?  How is your data structured?  If you have, say columns of article_id, comment_id, and comment_date (where comment_id ties back to article_id and each comment_id has a unique comment_date), you can simply do a "select article_id from [whatever table or tables...may have to do a join] where comment_date>='20110202'".

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong. look at the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery.  Unfortunately your question doesn't give me much for schema...so I'll invent as I go.  Lets say you have a table 'Article' with article_id as it's PK and your other table is comments (links on article_ID).  I'm assuming article_id + date makes a comment unique.

```
Select article.article_id, comment.comment_text,comment.comment_date from article
inner join (select min(comment_date) 'comment_date', article_id 
           from comment 
           where comment_date < '2010-02-02' 
           group by article_id) c 
       on c.article_id = article.article_id
inner join comment on comment.article_id = c.article_id and c.comment_date = comment.comment_date
```

You can use subqueries as tables within joins.  Use the subquery to isolate the single comment you want, then join back to the comment table to get the comment text.  Hopefully this made sense.  I don't have a MYSQL database to test this on, but I think the syntax should work (it does on MSSQL atleast)

editted for formatting.  And you can include a where statement at the bottom of this query to filter what articles you wanted to see.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to query comments greater than your date, returning article ID (you do have a normalised structure, right?  It's hard to tell without any detail).

To find the comment closest to your date, order the data by comment date in ascending order and take the first.

Comment: If it was so easy I woludn't asked, but yes it is normalised. t's really hard to explain my problem so I gave an example of SQL code. I think you have misunderstood me

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 a.* from articles a
inner join comments c on c.articleid = a.id
where c.date > '2011-02-02'
order by c.date asc
```

That should do it, although I'm not super familiar with MySQL.

Comment: It's really hard to explain my problem so I gave an example of SQL code. I think you have misunderstood me